# How to rewrite URL PrestaShop to hide folder?

Tags: url-rewriting, prestashop

I would like to hide my folder where PrestaShop is installed.

To access my shop, I must write http://domain.com/prestashop.

But I want access to my shop like this: http://domain.com.

How can I do this?

Comment: You must point your domain name to a specific subfolder. Could you provide more detailed information about your hosting provider? Check my answer also.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to your server configuration. 
Add this .htaccess to your / directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Prestashop/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Prestashop/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Don't forget to change your shop_url in SEO / URL.

Answer (score 0):

You must point your domain name to a specific subfolder.

If you point domain.com on prestashop subfolder then you should change it in your back office:

Preferences -> SEO & URLs
[image]

**After the change you should disable Friendly URL and then enable it again - Enabling Friendly URL generates .htaccess**